# Unknown Function: vundle#begin

Tags: vim, cygwin, vim-plugins

I cloned the vundle files into my home directory under cygwin

Then I fallowed the instructions at: https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim

Since I'm running vim under cygwin i change the runtime path in my `.vimrc` file to:

```
set rtp+=C:cygwin64/home/USERNAME/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/
call vundle#begin('C:/cygwin64/home/USERNAME/.vim/bundle/')
```

Now every time I run vim under cygwin i get the fallowing errors:

```
Error detected while processing /home/username/.vimrc
line 7:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#begin
line 10:
E492: Not an editor comand: Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
line 15:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#end
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

after pressing Enter, vim runs normally but with no vundle.

Questions:

1. Any ideas what could be wrong?
2. is vundle compatible with cygwin?

Comment: under cygwin you should use posix path like `/home/USERNAME/.vim/bundle/` not  `C:/cygwin64/home/USERNAME/.vim/bundle/` that not all programs manage

Comment: Thanks, That resolved the problem, and led to a realization. I really appreciate your comment.

Answer (score -1):

This line:

```
Error detected while processing /home/username/.vimrc
```

should give you a pretty good idea of what you did wrong.